# is there any python code to disable the mxnet console logs while executing the face detector and face encoder models

Tags: python-3.x, face-detection, mxnet

Mxnet framework producing console logs while model loading and inferences of face model.
Please find below the console logs which is producing while executing the python code.

[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:208: Loading symbol saved by previous version v0.8.0. Attempting to upgrade...
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:216: Symbol successfully upgraded!
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:208: Loading symbol saved by previous version v0.8.0. Attempting to upgrade...
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:216: Symbol successfully upgraded!
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:208: Loading symbol saved by previous version v0.8.0. Attempting to upgrade...
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:216: Symbol successfully upgraded!
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:208: Loading symbol saved by previous version v0.8.0. Attempting to upgrade...
[12:26:56] ../src/nnvm/legacy_json_util.cc:216: Symbol successfully upgraded!
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.
[12:27:49] ../src/executor/graph_executor.cc:1991: Subgraph backend MKLDNN is activated.

Please help to disable these console logs on the terminal or divert these logs into the file.

Thanks in advance to assist me to solve this problem.

I tried various approaches to handle these console logs, all are mentioned below :

1. Use the logging library by setting the "debugging" log status.
2. Pass the verbose parameter in "mx.model.FeedForward.load()" load function of mxnet.

None of the above mentioned approaches not given the exact solution.